# Template not updating when using Service Store (BehaviorSubject) to communicate between component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm using a service store to communicate between two components that aren't relatives. The component that is subscribed to the service variable teste, is getting the current value but it updates its template only the first time

[image]
[image]

Here's an image while debugging. Was you can see, the variable has value, but it doesn't update template.

[image]

LoggedInstanceStore

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Instance } from 'src/app/features/cadastros/instancia/instancia.component';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoggedInstanceStore {
    private _loggedInstance: Instance = null

    public trackerLoggedInstance = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this._loggedInstance);

    public teste = this.trackerLoggedInstance.asObservable();

    getLoggedInstanceValue() {
        return this.teste
    }

    setLoggedInstanceValue(loggedInstance: Instance) {
        this.trackerLoggedInstance.next(loggedInstance)
    }

    resetLoggedInstanceValue(): void {
        this.trackerLoggedInstance.next(this._loggedInstance);
    }
}
```

InstanceLoginComponent's login method. It's here I set the value for the first time

```
 login() {    
    let instanceLogin = this.instanceLoginForm.getRawValue()
    this.storage.setInstanceLogin(instanceLogin.instanceId)

    this.loggedInstanceStore.setLoggedInstanceValue(instanceLogin.instanceId)
    this.route.navigate(['app/cadastro/sistema'])
  }
```

Here's the component that I'm having the issue

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Instance } from 'src/app/features/cadastros/instancia/instancia.component';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LoggedInstanceStore } from './logged-instance.store';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logged-instance',
  templateUrl: './logged-instance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logged-instance.component.scss'],
})
export class LoggedInstanceComponent implements OnInit{

  loggedInstance: Instance;


  constructor(
    private loggedInstanceStore: LoggedInstanceStore,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    // const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    const browserLang = localStorage.getItem('appLanguage')
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|pt/) ? browserLang : 'en');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInstanceStore.teste
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data){
          this.loggedInstance = data
          this.ref.detectChanges()
        }        
      })
  }

}
```

And here's the component that also changes the LoggedStore's teste variable value

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Instance } from '../../cadastros/instancia/instancia.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/core/storage/storage.service';
import { LoggedInstanceStore } from 'src/app/components/header/logged-instance/logged-instance.store';
import { UtilsService } from 'src/app/services/utils/utils.service';
import { LoaderService } from 'src/app/components/loader/loader.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  timer: 6000,
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-sm btn-success ',
  },
  animation: false
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-instance',
  templateUrl: './change-instance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-instance.component.scss']
})
export class ChangeInstanceComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  instances: Instance[] = []
  changeInstanceForm: FormGroup
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private loggedInstanceStore: LoggedInstanceStore,
    private utilsService: UtilsService,
    private loaderService: LoaderService
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.instances = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['instances'];

    this.changeInstanceForm = this.fb.group({
      instance: ['']
    })
  }



  alterar() {
    debugger
    this.loaderService.show()
    let instanceSelected: Instance = this.changeInstanceForm.getRawValue();
    this.storageService.setInstanceLogin(instanceSelected)
    this.loggedInstanceStore.setLoggedInstanceValue(instanceSelected)
    this.utilsService.showAlertRequestSuccess

    this.loaderService.hide()

    Toast.fire(`Alteração efetuado com sucesso`, '', 'success')

    this.changeInstanceForm.reset()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out where I was going wrong. The ChangeInstanceComponent has a form with just one formControl named "instance". In the method alterar() I was getting the value of the form with `this.changeInstanceForm.getRawValue()` and then it returned an object with this structure

```
{
  "instance": {
    "Id": "10",
    "Name": "CBR",
    "ChannelId": 46,
    "ChannelName": "Confluence"
  }
}
```

That was the problem. Because the LoggedInstanceComponent expects an object with this structure

```
{
  "Id": "8",
  "Name": "ABC Pneus",
  "ChannelId": 43,
  "ChannelName": "Intragroup"
}
```

I just changed the way of getting the form values like this

```
changeInstanceForm.get('instance').value;
```